# Excel VBA How to access data created in Thisworkbook module from Module1 module

Tags: excel, vba

What I am trying to do is this:

In the ThisWorkbook module:

```
Option Explicit
'//== Does something need to go up here?  ==//
_________________

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Public cellArray() As String
    
    '//==  init cellArray() ==//
    cellArray(0) = "start"      '//== for example  ==//
    
End Sub
```

In the Module1 module:

```
Option Explicit
'//== Does something need to go up here?  ==//
_________________

Sub mySub()

Dim localvariable as string

    local variable = ThisWorkbook.cellArray(0)      '//== for example  ==//
    '//== Does something different need to go here?  ==//

End Sub
```

Is something like this even possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

ThisWorkbook:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ReDim cellArray(0)
    cellArray(0) = "start"      
End Sub
```

Module1:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public cellArray() As String

Sub mySub()
    Dim localvariable as string
    localvariable = cellArray(0)
    Debug.Print localvariable     
End Sub
```

Comment: This did not work. No compile errors were generated, but when mysub is run, both cellArray(0) and local variable contain empty strings. My guess is that cellArray(0) in the ThisWorkbook module is deallocated when the End Sub of the Private Sub Workbook_Open() procedure is executed.

Comment: Apologies I made a typo in my `Workbook_Open` posted code - `Dim cellArray(0)` should have been `ReDim cellArray(0)`  Corrected above.